# Como fazer para controlar a quantidade de Toasts que são exibidos sem que eles formem uma fila de exibição?

Tags: android

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo Android que basicamente é um jogo. Na Activity principal há um botão para começar a jogar e outros botões que também fazem parte do jogo, mas se o usuário apertar qualquer outro botão senão o de começar, um Toast é exibido pedindo para que ele aperte o botão de início. O problema é que ele pode apertar outros botões várias vezes, inundando a tela de Toasts que se repetem o número de vezes que foram solicitados.

O desejável é que não houvesse fila alguma, ou seja, o Toast só ser exibido se não houver nenhum outro Toast em exibição.

Comment: Recomendo uma outra maneira, você pode deixar os botões invisíveis, e quando clicar no começar então deixar visível novamente, Assim vai deixar a tela mais limpa e não terá o problema das `Toast`

Comment: Infelizmente eu não posso deixar os botões invisíveis, mexeria muito com a interface do jogo. Eu estava mais procurando por algum método inerente à classe Toast que retornasse um valor para se houver algum Toast sendo exibido, assim seria só verificar o estado dessa variável e só exibir o Toast se ela não estivesse "setada".

Comment: Serve deixar ele desabilitado? Assim não responderá a nenhuma ação de click

Comment: Na verdade o Toast ajudaria o usuário a saber que esse botão é o que inicia o jogo, então eu vejo ele como necessário. Só não queria que ele ficasse sendo exibido várias vezes se o usuário apertar o botão várias vezes.